# Are constructors and/or initializations thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Imagine the following class.

```java
class Whatever {
    Object obj;
    Whatever() {
        obj = new Object();
    }
    Object get() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

As threads usually write to their local cache I assume the following:

If a thread `A` creates an instance of `Whatever` and a thread `B` calls `get()` on that instance, it *could* happen that `B` gets a `null` because the reference for `obj` was written in the locale cache of `A` only, not in the shared cache.

Am I right? And what about other kind of initializations?

---

I've tried to produce that behaviour with the following code.

```java
class Main {

    static Whatever whatever = new Whatever();


    static class Whatever {
        Object obj;
        Whatever() {
            obj = new Object();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                whatever = new Whatever();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.println(whatever.obj);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The output is never `null` but I think it *should* be sometimes. Maybe the code is just trying it wrongly ..

Comment: Are constructors thread safe? Yes. There is no shared state in your original version. That is, the constructor cannot return until `obj` has been set. If another thread called `get()` it would be on a different instance. Because the constructor setting `obj` hasn't completed. And thus it must be a reference to a different `Whatever` (we just finished making "this" one).

Comment: To put that more simply, it's impossible for two threads to be constructing the same object instance at the same time. And as initializers are run by constructors, they are also thread-safe.

Comment: Two put it even yet another way, if two threads called the same constructor at exactly same time, each thread would get its own *separate* object.  Separate objects mean no shared memory, and hence they can't possibly interfere with one another.  OTOH it's possible for a constructor to do things that aren't thread safe (like write to global variables) but it's relatively rare to do that.

Comment: In your second example, the output is probably never null because `t1` is so short and runs immediately.  You can't count on the timing of independently running threads.  If you want to provoke some non-deterministic behavior, then that's exactly the time when the threads will decide to behave deterministically.  Basically: you can't win unless you synchronize.

Comment: The output can never be null. The constructor executes before the assignment to `whatever`, so `whatever.obj` can never be null. @markspace

Comment: Oh right.  The OP does make a static assignment to `whatever` right at the very beginning.  Well that explains it. @user207421

Comment: @markspace That's not the point. The point is that `obj` can never be null when `whatever` isn't.

Comment: @user207421 wait, what? You are saying all the hard work to make applications thread safe was obsolete, because out-of-order writes do not happen? Has someone captured your account?

Comment: @akuzminykh “it *should* be sometimes” is wrong. It *could* sometimes, because the lack of thread safe constructs *can* lead to unintended behavior. The JVM is not obligated to inject such behavior. As markspace said, the loops don’t need to run interleaved. Further, there’s not only no guaranty to observe the updated `obj` variable, there’s also no guaranty to  observe the updated `whatever`. Of course, when the second thread doesn’t observe new references in `whatever`, it doesn’t matter whether it would observe updates of `obj`. Also, the synchronization inside `println` can have an effect.